# Why Azure reserves first four IP address of a subnet

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

As the question says, I want to know, why Azure reserves first four and the last IP address of a subnet?

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Yes. Azure reserves 5 IP addresses within each subnet. These are x.x.x.0-x.x.x.3 and the last address of the subnet. x.x.x.1-x.x.x.3 is reserved in each subnet for Azure services.

x.x.x.0: Network address

x.x.x.1: Reserved by Azure for the default gateway

x.x.x.2, x.x.x.3: Reserved by Azure to map the Azure DNS IPs to the VNet space

x.x.x.255: Network broadcast address

[See the Azure faq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-faq)

Comment: Wish someone clear the edit queue. This needs a little [formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Azure reserves the first and last address in each subnet for protocol conformance. And three additional addresses are reserved for Azure service usage.  Azure do not go into detail about the services that uses the reserved ip addresses, but we can say for sure that the default gateway is an Azure service that will use the reserved ip addresses